# sed if pattern match copy pattern line along with n number of lines after this to another file

Tags: windows, batch-file, gnu-sed

I am looking for a `sed` command to match pattern and copy pattern line and `n` number of lines after this line.
pattern is `01`, `02`, `03` sequence.

Example:

```
group-title=01- line1
http://www.yahoo.com
group-title=02- local3
http://www.altavista.com
group-title=01- koko1
http://www.bbc.com
```

Required output:

```
group-title=01- line1
http://www.yahoo.com
group-title=01- koko1
http://www.bbc.com
```

I tried

```
sed -n "/01- /p" orignal.txt > copyof.txt
```

but this only copy line which matches pattern.
I have to copy the 2nd line also as second line has its link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep -A` is the better way to do this (see Timur Shtatland's answer), but if you really want to do it with `sed`, here's how:

```
sed -n '/01- / {p;n;p;}'      # print match + next line
sed -n '/01- / {p;n;p;n;p;}'  # print match + next 2 lines
```

Explanation: when it finds a matching line, `{p;n;p;}` will **p**rint that line, get the **n**ext line, and **p**rint that.

Note that this won't notice additional matches within the extra lines being printed. So for example if there are two matching lines in a row, it'll print them but not the next line as you might expect (and `grep -A` will do).

Comment: what if 01-[space] also have "01-[space] line1" , means what if I want to include "" double qoute in my search pattern. any solution acceptable eiter sed or grep, i am using windows

Comment: @Rizwan.A The easiest way to include double-quotes in the search pattern is to use single-quotes around the entire argument (I'll edit my answer to show this). Alternately, you can include double-quotes inside a double-quoted argument by escaping them (e.g. `sed -n "/01- \"double-quoted text\"/ {p;n;p;}"`).

Comment: my search pattern like this ```group-title="01- channel1" ``` and I have to search ```group-title="01- *" ```, * means any text after 01- , can you please help me in this specific pattern

Comment: @Rizwan.A `sed` uses regular expressions (the "basic" variant by default) rather than wildcard patterns, so the match-anything pattern is `.*` rather than just `*`. You might also want to add `^` at the beginning to require that it start at the beginning of the line. So if I understand right, the command would be `sed -n '/^group-title="01- .*"/ {p;n;p;}'`

Comment: thanks for reply but .* not working , and pattern is not in beginning, its some where in middle of line so ^ is not applicable. thanks. command tried by me with your help in my windows is ```sed -n "/group-title="01- .*"/ {p;n;p;}" sourcefile.txt > destinationfile.txt```

Comment: @Rizwan.A You need to either put single-quotes around the argument (now double-quotes like you have here), or escape the double-quotes inside the pattern. Try `sed -n '/group-title="01- .*"/ {p;n;p;}' sourcefile.txt > destinationfile.txt`

Comment: facing error ```sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `'' ``` for information I am using sed on Windows cmd not in Linux/ Unix, windows works with double qoute

Comment: @Rizwan.A Oh, I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with Windows CMD; If I'm reading [this](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) right, you might need to use outer double-quotes, and escape the double-quotes in the pattern with `^` instead of `\`. If that doesn't work I'm afraid I just don't know.

Comment: ok its done, lots of thanks for your expert help. I use following to fulfil my need with you help. ```sed -n "/01- \"double-quoted text\"/ {p;n;p;}" ``` and made slight change in it ```sed -n "$!N;/group-title=\"01- News\"/p" sourcefile.txt >> d:\destinationfile.txt``` to fulfill my need I used multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -A1 'group-title=01-' orig.txt > copy.txt
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses option:

`-A num, --after-context=num` : Print `num` lines of trailing context after each match.  See also the `-B` and `-C` options.

Comment: i prefer sed , can you help

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez ':a;s/(([^=]*=)01-[^=]*)\20[02-9][^=]*\n/\1/;ta' input_file
group-title=01- line1
http://www.yahoo.com
group-title=01- koko1
http://www.bbc.com
```

Comment: not working in windows cmd